# Can you select the value of a REDIS key by the number of key in list

Tags: redis

[image]

I'm working with redis 2.8 with win10-64. As you can see in the screenshot I have a number of long keys. Rather than type or cut and paste them , is there a way to get the value by selecting their number in the list (you can see my 2 failed attempts) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you select the value of a REDIS key by the number of key in list?

***NO***, You can't.

Because Redis-cli does not support this feature. And even though if you know the key, you can't fetch the data without knowing it's data type.

Suppose you have a set/HashMap corresponding to a key. For that key command `get <key>` will not work for that typed data.